# How to deselect selected select box in variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where i want to deselect all the selected select boxes inside the variable in jquery. Below is my html and jquery code.

I just wanted that when i clicked on a button and get all the html in a variable and then want to deselect all the selected select box and bind it into the variable again in jquery. Below is my code. Please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var html = "<tr>" + '<input type = "hidden"  name = "translator_approved_for_id[]" value="-1">' + $("#add_more_service").html() + '</tr>';

$(html).find("option:selected").removeAttr('selected', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr><input type="hidden" name="translator_approved_for_id[]" value="-1">
  <td>
    <select id="translator_service1" name="translator_service[]" class="form-control">
      <option value="select">--select--</option>
      <option value="Annotation">Annotation</option>
      <option value="Assessment" selected="selected">Assessment</option>
      <option value="Coding">Coding</option>
      <option value="Corporate Training">Corporate Training</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="translator_source_language1" name="translator_source_language[]" class="form-control">
      <option value="select">--select--</option>
      <option value="Abkhazian">Abkhazian</option>
      <option value="Achinese">Achinese</option>
      <option value="Acoli" selected="selected">Acoli</option>
      <option value="Adangme">Adangme</option>
      <option value="Afar">Afar</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="translator_target_language1" name="translator_target_language[]" class="form-control">
      <option value="select">--select--</option>
      <option value="Abkhazian">Abkhazian</option>
      <option value="Achinese">Achinese</option>
      <option value="Acoli">Acoli</option>
      <option value="Adangme">Adangme</option>
      <option value="Afar" selected="selected">Afar</option>
      <option value="Afrikaans">Afrikaans</option>
      <option value="Akan">Akan</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="translator_industry" name="translator_industry[]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
      <option value="Automobiles">Automobiles</option>
      <option value="Aviation" selected="selected">Aviation</option>
      <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="show_approved_clients('14','ODk3NQ==')">
  </td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: removeAttr() should only have the first parameter

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GiacomoDeLiberali but its not working. I tried this. How can i bind again into the variable after deselecting all select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `html` variable after removing attribute, for this [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) to end the most recent filtering operation and return the set of matched elements i.e. `$(html)`  then use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property.

```
html = $(html)
    .find("option:selected") 
    .removeAttr('selected') //Removes selected attribute 
    .end() //End the most recent filtering operation i.e. target back
    .prop('outerHTML'); //Get outerHTML of element
```

Comment: Thanks @Satpal you save my day. Its working and also please explain this